# Opencv3 is not installed for python3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I am using pyenv for python3.4 and want to install opencv3.

```
$ brew install opencv3 --HEAD --with-python3 --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --with-contrib --with-opengl --with-qt5
```

but in /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/HEAD-8e8da3f/lib/ there is no python3.4 
it only have python2.7. 
i don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install anaconda and run the collowing command:

`conda install -c menpo opencv3`